# Multiple taxonomies in URL filter (both AND and OR type)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filtering, url-parameters, custom-taxonomy

I'm working on a webshop that's running on Wordpress+Woocommerce. I can't find a way to filter the products via URL by custom taxonomies with the OR operator. Filtering with the AND operator works fine. Basically, for some taxonomy filters I need to add another value, so that it would be shown with the rest of the results (not instead). I've seen that you can use "+" in URL to filter by multiple categories, but it doesn't seem to work with taxonomies. Only commas work for values.

So, for example, I have an URL with filtered products like this:

mywebsite.com/?filter_color=29,50

Now, if the filter is "color", I want to add another value to its results, like so:

mywebsite.com/?filter_color=29,50+70

So it should show products that have color attributes with ID's 29,50 (only those that have both of these values) plus products with color's attribute ID 70.

Sounds simple enough, but I can't find any info on how to achieve this. I couldn't even find the function that checks these GET parameters. I wouldn't like to make my own filter from scratch, because this addition is all I need. As for the check whether it's a "color" filter or some other - I could do it with JS, so I only need to know how to add the filter value with OR operator. But any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Sounds simple enough". I actually think this sounds pretty hard. There's a good example in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for multiple taxonomies that might be easy to switch to 'and' 29 and 50 OR id = 70. best guess is you can add products via `loop_shop_post_in` filter. But this seems like an odd use case to me. I can't imagine using the layered nav widget for some blue and red... OR white.

Comment: In PHP I would simply check GET for the attribute, then if the attribute is THIS than I'd add the OR statement to the query, otherwise would run the regular AND query. That's why it sounds easy to me, I'd simply then put additional " OR id=50" to the existing query.

Of course the example with color is a bad one, and I'm not going to use it for colors. I'm going to use it for product types, but I picked color for the example because I thought it would be easier to understand. Otherwise I would have to go into too many unneeded details.

Comment: So, basically, I need to modify the query that WP runs when I type "?filter_taxonomyName=taxonomyID" in the URL.

Comment: And thanks for the link and suggestion for the loop! But I think there should be a more "beautiful" way to do this, because then I'd run 2 queries instead of a single, modified, one.

Comment: Well, actually, let me try to explain, it's not that tricky. I have an attribute that describes products' specialization. It can be this, or that, or universal. So if the user is searching for this or that he should also get the universal products as the result, because it would fit any of these filters. I want to make it not just intuitive for the user to navigate, but also for the shop managers to classify, so I decided to use one attribute and use the universal parameter as one of this attribute's values (instead of using tags etc.).

Comment: I solved it with javascript. I check whether the "universal" filters are applied to the URL and if so then I make an ajax request to get the universal products and add them to the results.

Comment: I have the same question, and I agree with you that this is something that should be simple to do. So if I understand your last suggestion, you add another filter "universal" to the URL and you pick this up with javascript on the archive page, in order to make the AJAX request? If you have code to share, that would be great :-)